# Problema con la función random en buscaminas hecho en python

Tags: python, random

Tengo un problema con el proyecto de buscaminas, pues después de que introduzca una opcion en el programa principal, se me queda atascado el programa y no sigue, después al darle al botón del stop cuadrado rojo, me sale un error relacionado seguramente con la funcion `random()`.

```
Buscaminas: 

Para poder jugar primero tendrá que seleccionar el nivel que usted desee.
1.Nivel principiante

2.Nivel intermedio

3.Nivel experto

4.Para determinar la matriz

Introduzca la opción que quiere: 1


  File "<ipython-input-3-11f9c3dbec43>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/shexing/Escritorio/Proyecto/buscaminas.py', wdir='/home/shexing/Escritorio/Proyecto')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/shexing/Escritorio/Proyecto/buscaminas.py", line 21, in <module>
    T.poner_bombas_tablero()

  File "/home/shexing/Escritorio/Proyecto/tablero.py", line 109, in poner_bombas_tablero
    j=randint(0,int(self.col)-1)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 221, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)

KeyboardInterrupt`
```

Esta son las clases `Casilla` y `Tablero`:

```
class Casilla (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bomba=False
        self.valor=0
        self.estado='x'
    def get_estado(self):
        return str(self.estado)

    def set_estado(self,estado):
        self.estado=estado

    def get_bomba(self):
        return bool(self.bomba)

    def set_bomba(self,bomba):
        self.bomba=bomba

    def get_valor(self):
        return int(self.valor)

    def set_valor(self, valor):
        self.valor=valor

class Tablero (object):
    def __init__(self,fil,col,minas): 
        self.fil=fil
        self.col=col
        self.minas=minas
        self.casillas_marcadas=None
        self.casillas_levantadas=None
        self.tiempo_inicio=0
        self.tablero=[[0]*self.col]*self.fil
        for i in range (self.fil):
            for j in range (self.col):
                self.tablero[i][j]=Casilla()
    def poner_bombas_tablero(self):
        n=0
        while n<self.minas:
            i=randint(0,self.fil-1)
            j=randint(0,self.col-1)
            if self.tablero[i][j].get_valor()!=-1:
                self.tablero[i][j].set_valor(-1)
                self.tablero[i][j].set_bomba(True)
                n+=1
        for i in range(self.fil):
            for j in range(self.col):
                if self.tablero[i][j].get_valor()==-1:
                    if i==0:
                        if j==0:
                            for x in range(0,2):
                                for y in range(0,2):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)
                        if j==self.col-1:
                            for x in range(0,2):
                                for y in range(-1,1):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)
                        else:
                            for x in range(0,2):
                                for y in range(-1,2):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)
                    elif i==self.fil-1:
                        if j==0:
                            for x in range(-1,1):
                                for y in range(0,2):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)

                        elif j==self.col-1:
                            for x in range(-1,1):
                                for y in range(-1,1):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)
                        else:                                       
                            for x in range(-1,1):
                                for y in range(-1,2):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)

                    elif j==0:
                        if i>0 and i<self.fil-1:
                            for x in range(-1,2):
                                for y in range(0,2):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)

                    elif j==self.col-1:
                        if i>0 and i<self.fil-1:
                             for x in range(-1,2):
                                for y in range(-1,1):
                                    if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)

                    else:
                         for x in range(-1,2):
                            for y in range(-1,2):
                                if self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()!=-1:
                                        self.tablero[i+x][j+y].set_valor(self.tablero[i+x][j+y].get_valor()+1)
```

Comment: El error que te sale al abortar la ejecución no implica que esa función sea la que te causa el problema, sino que era la que se estaba ejecutando en el momento en que abortaste. Tiene toda la pinta de que tienes un bucle infinito en la función `poner_bombas_tablero()` por el que nunca sale de esa función. Sería necesario ver tu código para un diagnóstico más preciso.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con la funcón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Has sido mordido por la Pitón!

La forma en que inicializas `self.tablero` contiene una trampa en la que tarde o temprano alguien cae. Para entenderlo mejor, lo ejemplifico fuera de las clases, quitando los `self`, y por tanto equivale a este trocito de código:

```
# Por poner un valor concreto:
fil = 10
col = 10
tablero=[[0]*col]*fil
```

Con ello pretendias crear una matriz de 10x10 (en este ejemplo) rellena con ceros. Si miramos el valor de la variable `tablero`, efectivamente veremos:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(tablero)
```

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Pero ¡cuidado! ¡Esto no es lo que parece! Debido a la forma en que has construido esta lista, no se trata de 10 filas independientes, sino de la misma fila repetida diez veces. Podemos comprobarlo fácilmente así:

```
tablero[0][1] = 5   # Cambio un elemento de la primera fila
pprint.pprint(tablero)
```

```
[[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

El resultado que vemos se entiende si sabemos que una lista en python almacena referencias a otros objetos. La lista `tablero` está almacenando 10 referencias **iguales** a la misma lista que es una de las filas.

Por tanto, tu función que pone bombas, no importa en qué fila las ponga porque en realidad sólo hay una. En cuanto haya puesto 10 bombas, la fila completa se habrá llenado (y por tanto el tablero completo). No será capaz de encontrar más huecos libres y por eso nunca sale del bucle.

Solución: Inicializa el tablero de este otro modo:

```
tablero = [ [0 for j in range(col)] for i in range(fil)]
```

Ahora ya son filas independientes, como podemos comprobar repitiendo el experimento de cambiar un elemento:

```
tablero[0][1] = 5
pprint.pprint(tablero)
```

```
[[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

En tu caso, de hecho, en lugar de inicializar con ceros podrías inicializar directamente con `Casilla()`, evitándote el bucle que haces después. Toda la inicialización del tablero podría ser:

```
class Tablero:
    def __init__(self,fil,col,minas): 
        self.fil=fil
        self.col=col
        self.minas=minas
        self.casillas_marcadas=None
        self.casillas_levantadas=None
        self.tiempo_inicio=0
        self.tablero=[[Casilla() for j in range(col)] for i in range(fil)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto he conseguido arreglar el programa!